# SecureSocial 2 - using registration and login with own database [play framework 2]

Tags: playframework-2.0, securesocial

1. I want to use registration and login in secure social 2 with my own database. I tried using `doSave` method in `InMemoryUserService` class, where I am not able to retrieve password. (I am using Java)
2. How can I authenticate user logging using `doFind` method.

Please help me on this.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve ? Using secure social to authenticate with your own HTML form with user & password ?

Comment: I want to save users information in my own database, and authenticate user at login.

Comment: With Facebook, Google, your own form ?

Comment: in  'InMemoryUserService' if I want to use 'doFind' then I could use 'userId.id, userId.provider' but I could not see anything to get password and so how would I compare that with database

Comment: with my own database and I am using the HTML form as given in securesocial

Answer (score 2):

For using the HTML form authentication, you have to:

1. register the [UsernamePasswordProvider](https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial/blob/master/module-code/app/securesocial/core/providers/UsernamePasswordProvider.scala)
2. implement the [doFind](https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial/blob/master/samples/java/demo/app/service/InMemoryUserService.java#L42) method of your service, by creating a new instance of a [SocialUser](https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial/blob/master/module-code/app/securesocial/core/java/SocialUser.java) from the id and provider by searching in your database. In this SocialUser, you have to populate the [passwordInfo](https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial/blob/master/module-code/app/securesocial/core/java/SocialUser.java#L74) property with the one from your database
3. the UsernamePasswordProvider will check the password for you through [this line of code](https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial/blob/master/module-code/app/securesocial/core/providers/UsernamePasswordProvider.scala#L47):

   `if user.passwordInfo.isDefined && use[PasswordHasher].matches(user.passwordInfo.get, credentials._2)`

Comment: thanks for reply. **1** What do you mean by register 'UsernamePasswordProvider'. I am just looking for 'userpass' provider **2** While implementing 'doFind' if I do 'user.passwordInfo.password=string from database' will it be wrong?